# How to show a tmux environment variable in the status bar (as window format)

Tags: bash, statusbar, tmux

What it comes down to is, I would like to

- print a variable unique to the window ,or
- run a script unique to the window

and use the output in the status bar such that each window status is unique. I've tried to make it more clear through 2 scenarios:

---

**Scenario 1**

I'm trying to print a unique per window variable in the status bar. I've opened a shell inside tmux and have stored the tmux environment variable locally (per session) and globally (for all sessions) with the following commands, respectively:

```
bash> tmux set-environment TMUX_STATUS_1 localvalue1
bash> tmux set-environment -g TMUX_STATUS_1 globalvalue1
```

I can verify these values for instance by going the another shell (in the same session) and typing:

```
bash> tmux show-environment TMUX_STATUS_1
    TMUX_STATUS_1=localvalue1
bash> tmux show-environment -g TMUX_STATUS_1
    TMUX_STATUS_1=globalvalue1
```

I've tried to print the above value in the statusbar (both the local and global value) and have configured the window format as follows:

```
WINDOW='[#(tmux show-environment -g TMUX_STATUS_#I 2>&1)]'
setw -g window-status-current-format $WINDOW
setw -g window-status-format $WINDOW
```

Initially it only showed windows as '[]', after this I added the redirection of stderr to stdout and got the status bar showing the following:

```
[unknown variable: TMUX_STATUS_1] [unknown variable: TMUX_STATUS_2] [...
```

What needs to be changed to make the statusbar show (according to previous commands):

```
[globalvalue1] [unknown variable: TMUX_STATUS_2] [...
```

PS: it's not a status bar refresh issues, as i've used the following command after setting the variable to manually force a refresh of the statusbar:

```
tmux refresh-client -S
```

---

**Scenario 2**

I've written a small bash script called 'tmuxscript' containing only:

```
echo "$(date '+%S') window:$(tmux display -p '#I') args:$@"
```

I updated my PATH variable and I have changed the window format to '[#(tmuxscript arg1 #I)]'. The output looks like:

```
[47 window:1 args:arg1] [47 window:1 args:arg1] [...
```

The time updates nicely. Printing the window index inside the script doesn't seem to work. The number 1 represents the window index of the currently focused window. This value is set for all windows, which is not what I want. I would at least expect to see (note the window index number) :

```
[47 window:1 args:arg1] [47 window:2 args:arg1] [...
```

Also, #I isn't getting past to the script, but the text 'arg1' is. How can I pas tmux variables to the script?

---

**EDIT**: I have now also tried setting the window status to:

```
'[#(tmux show-environment -g TMUX_STATUS_$\(tmux display -p "#I"\) 2>&1 | sed "s:^.*=::" )]'
```

Which gives me the following when the active (focused) window index is 1:

```
[globalvalue1] [globalvalue1] [...
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: my guess of the problem is, the `#I` was not expanded in `#(..)`. but it was expanded in the error message: `unknow...  :Tmux_.._#I` it is likely working like that. In another word, your shell command is looking for `tmux_status_#I` which doesn't exist.

Comment: Then why would the error message report the right variable? If I run in the terminal (in tmux window with index 1): 'tmux showenv -g TMUX_STATUS_#I' it returns: 'unknown variable: TMUX_STATUS_#I'. When trying to run custom scripts though, you are right. The #I does not get expanded/passed (See scenario 2).

Comment: maybe I didn't explain it clearly. the error msg original was `TMUX_STATUS_#I not found`  because you set the window name, the `#I` was replaced with `1,2,3...` winIdx. that's why you got the "correct" variable name in error msg. but you got the `#I` in shell error msg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.

The problem lies in the fact that you are obligated to use the -g (global) flag when specifying a window-status in *.tmux.conf*.

**.tmux.conf**:

```
WINDOW="[#I #20W]"
set-window -g window-status-current-format $WINDOW
set-window -g window-status-format $WINDOW
```

The key is to make the status local after creating a window. Also, each window needs to be uniquely identifiable. Luckily this can be done by tmux variable 'window_id'. A small script, shown below, will output a variable unique to the window with this id as its first argument:

**~/tmuxstatus**:

```
#!/bin/bash

VARIABLE="W_$1"
VALUE=$(tmux show-environment -g $VARIABLE 2>&1)
VALUE=${VALUE#*=}
echo $VALUE
```

There is probably a TMUX only solution to make the status local, but I don't currently have the time. I'm using bash to do it with the aid of the environment variable PROMPT_COMMAND, which is evaluated just before the prompt is shown.

**.bashrc**:

```
function __prompt_command (){
   if [ -n "$TMUX" ] && [ ! -n "$TMUX_INIT" ]; then
        W=$(tmux display -p '#{window_id}')
        VARIABLE="W_$W"
        VALUE="value_$W"
        STATUS="[#I #(~/tmuxstatus $W)]"
        tmux set-option quiet on;
        tmux set-environment -g $VARIABLE $VALUE;
        tmux set-window window-status-current-format "$STATUS";
        tmux set-window window-status-format "$STATUS";
        export TMUX_INIT="done";
    fi; 
}
export PROMPT_COMMAND=__prompt_command
```

When changing the value of W_id, the window status changes also. It looks like:

```
[1 value_@0] [2 value_@1] [3 value_@2] [4 value_@3]
```

enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using the `echo` command. You can manually set the title using this syntax:

```bash
echo -ne "\033]0;$(tmux show-environment TMUX_STATUS_1)\007"
```

Try running that in different`tmux` windows and see if it changes the title.